# jQuery: сбрасывается при изменении данных на стр

Tags: jquery

Попробовал свои силы в `jQuery`, вещь интересная!
Только вот понять не могу

Сделал замену ссылок на чекбоксы на сервисе `ucoz` с помощью `jQuery`

[Пример](http://xn--80aa8aajoeeg.xn--p1ai/shop/256m2) - см блок слева с опциями товара, если отметить чекбокс, то происходит сортировка по выбранной опции, НО при этом сбрасывается подменка ((

Почему такое происходит? Не могу понять ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой-то скрипт у Вас заменяет все чекбоксы на span.

Comment: точняк, спасибо за помощь!